# Buscar data-id e Remover do banco de dados

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho este foreach()

```
<?php foreach($fotos_ingresso as $valor){ ?>
    <div id="fotos-listagem-imagem">
        <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirma-deletar-imagem" data-href="#" data-id="<?php echo $valor->inf_id; ?>" id="deletar-imagem"><img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/uploads/interno_fotos/'.$valor->inf_tipo.'/'.$valor->inf_imagem); ?>" class="img-responsive corte-imagem"></a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Dentro dele, estou passando id="deletar-imagem" e também o data-id.

De que forma eu consigo recuperar o data-id?
Eu fiz da seguinte forma:

```
$('#confirma-deletar-imagem').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {         
    var inf_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
});
```

Neste caso está retornando nullo. Quando clica na imagem, eu abro uma confirmação via modal... E quando clicar, deverá chamar o Ajax para remover. Porém, não sei nem como chamar o ajax para remover, depois do clique no botão chamado deletar-imagem-modal.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: O atributo `id` define um elemento único na página, então não faz sentido ter dentro de um `foreach`. Veja se consegue utilizar classes.

Comment: Foreach() é para que eu exiba as imagens do banco de dados, por isso estou usando o foreach()...

Comment: Sim, o problema não está em utilizar o `foreach`, mas em definir o atributo `id` do elemento dentro do laço. Isso iria criar na página vários elementos com o mesmo `id` e isso não é possível, pois `id` é único.

Comment: Mas com o Class não deu também... Apliquei o class e coloquei para buscar no class mas não retorna, retorna sempre 1, que é o primeiro ID

Comment: Pode atualizar o código da pergunta, se quiser. Busque também fazer um [mcve].

Comment: Sugiro incluir também o código de ajax que está a utilizar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dei uma alterada na sua função, e inseri a parte de chamar o ajax.

```
<?php foreach($fotos_ingresso as $valor){ ?>
    <div id="fotos-listagem-imagem">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirma-deletar-imagem" 
            data-href="#" data-id="<?php echo $valor->inf_id; ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/uploads/interno_fotos/'.$valor->inf_tipo.'/'.$valor->inf_imagem); ?>" 
            class="img-responsive corte-imagem">
        </a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>

<hidden id="hiddenValue" />

<script>
    $(function()){
        $('#confirma-deletar-imagem').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {         
            $("#hiddenValue").val() = $(this).attr('data-id');
        );

        $("#btnRemover").click(function(){
            var data = {
                id_img: $("#hiddenValue").val()
            };

            $.post( "ajax/delete.php", function( data ) {
                //aplicar seu retorno
            });
        });
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Olá, este confirmar aparece para que eu possa confirmar se realmente desejo excluir ou não. Ai clicando no botão sim, ele irá para a ação de exclusão. Seguindo seu exemplo, ele passaria direto, ou não?

Comment: Isto, iria excluir sem perguntar.. Editei minha resposta, e coloquei um confirm para fazer o questionamento de realmente excluir.

Comment: Esse ('show.bs.modal', function(e) já abre a modal de exclusão...

Comment: Entendi, então basta você colocar um hidden no seu documento para setar o valor temporário e coloque o ID do seu botão para que quando clicado ele execute o post. Já alterei a resposta.